# Customize Numix theme: title bar header height

Tags: themes, settings

I have installed Numix theme following these instructions (https://itsfoss.com/install-numix-ubuntu/)

I'd like to change the title bar height, making it slimmer.

Is there any css I could edit to achieve it?

edit: I'm using elementary loki

Answer (score 2):

Try this tool: https://github.com/actionless/oomox#oomox 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install oomox